# Why do I need to make an intermediate step on switching a pin from input to output On Atmega328p microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, avr

On the Atmega328p datasheet p.99 The following was mentioned.

> Switching Between Input and Output:

> When switching between tri-state ({DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b00) and output high ({DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b11),
> an intermediate state with either pull-up enabled {DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b01) or output low ({DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b10) must occur. Normally, the pull-up enabled state is fully acceptable, as a high-impedance environment will not notice the difference between a strong high driver and a pull-up. If this is not the case, the PUD bit in the MCUCR Register can be set to disable all pull-ups in all ports.
> Switching between input with pull-up and output low generates the same problem. The user must use either the tri-state ({DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b00) or the output high state ({DDxn, PORTxn} = 0b11) as an intermediate step.

Why Do I need such an intermediate step in the first place?

Comment: Because output would be undefined without pullup.  You want to transition from tri-state to high.  Whether you need it or not depends on what is connected to it.  Can you live with pin being preceived as a low by connected circuitry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is not a "you must" requirement but a reminder of the fact that the processor can *only update one register at a time*.

On the ATmega series, the input vs. output and the output value or pull-up are controlled by distinct registers with a bit per pin, and the processor can only modify one register at a time, so for any change which requires modifying both aspects of a given pin, there exists a brief instant in time when one aspect has been updated and the other has not.

What the paragraph does is discuss *strategy* for what order to modify the two registers in.  The chip itself isn't imposing an answer, but *external circuitry* might care.  The possibility is raised of going through additional steps to create a safe sequence of change.  But the requirement for a specific sequence comes from the needs of *external* circuitry, not the processor itself.

As a more general rule, one should be careful to make sure that the output level a drive will drive at is appropriate (or at least acceptable) before enabling the driver.   The paragraph discusses the complications arising from the controls being split over multiple bits and the output data register being re-used as a pullup control; hence the consequence are different than in chips which may use a *pair* of bits in the same register to control both direction and pull-up, and keep that distinct from an output data register which has no differing function in input mode.

**If one is not switching repeatedly between input and output modes while needing to maintain a given glitch-free state on a shared wire, this is likely of little concern.**  In many of the typical places where one would be (bit-bang I2C or multi-drop serial) idle-high paradigms with external pull-ups make it fairly safe to set the data register before setting the direction register.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit, Chris, explaining the function of the two bits? The way they're presented in the question it would appear that they could both be changed at once. I can't remember if I've studied this before.

Comment: @Transistor they can't be changed at the same time because the direction and output/pullup bits are in distinct registers at distinct addresses.  For each port, DDx is one register with a bitmap bit per pin, and PORTx is another register with a bitmap bit per pin.  The processor can only change the registers one at a time, so some intermediate state must briefly exist.

Comment: So basically the quoted  paragraph is just a complicated way of saying that it makes a difference in what order you are changing both bits - when both bits are changed. And that you have to make sure that any intermediate setting isn't harmful to what's connected to that pin.